# sql injection protect

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to prevent SQL Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Is this code protected enough against sql injection

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["user"]);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["pass"]);
$confirm_key=md5(uniqid(rand()));

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO members 
(user, pass, mail, confirm_key, country, city, www, credo)
VALUES  ('$user','$pass','$_POST[mail]','$confirm_key','$_POST[country]','$_POST[city]','$_POST[www]','$_POST[credo]')")
or die ("Error during INSERT INTO members:    " . mysql_error());
exit();
}
```

Is this the right way and must be each input (like country, city...) be protected ?

Comment: If you want to be really sure, you should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**DO NOT USE** `mysql_query` for new applications. You should be using `mysqli` or PDO to do your escaping with placeholders. There are [many examples](http://bobby-tables.com/php) you can use.

Generally your SQL should look like:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (column) VALUES (?)
```

It **SHOULD NOT** look like:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (column) VALUES('$dangerous_user_content')
```

If you use placeholders properly it's almost impossible to create a SQL injection hole.

Comment: Hm, ok, I will tray. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: You can see in your example how tricky and dangerous `mysql_query` is. You escaped `$user` and `$pass` but completely forgot about `$_POST[country]`. Spend the short amount of time to do it right and you'll be safe and secure. Always test your application with a variety of input, especially including both `'` and `"`.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Even the php docs say don't use mysql_real_escape_string